# cannot import name 'messagebox' from 'tk'Error

Tags: python, tkinter

I use Spyder ide from Anaconda, I just play around with python and try to make the message encode/decode. I get many error from installing the library tkinter and base64. Eventually it runs but have to change to pip install tk/pybase64 instead.
And after some trouble, there is new error that I completely don't know how to fix. Resources on the internet don't help me much.

ERROR: cannot import name 'messagebox' from 'tk'

```
import tk as tk
from tk import *
import pybase64
from tk import messagebox
tk.messagebox

root = Tk()

root.geometry("600x600")

root.title("TechVidvan Message Encryption and Decryption")


Msg = tk.StringVar()
key = tk.StringVar()
mode = tk.StringVar()
Result = tk.StringVar()

label = tk.Label(root, text='Enter Message', font=('Helvetica',10))
label.place(x=10,y=0)

mes = tk.Entry(root,textvariable=Msg, font=('calibre',10,'normal'))
mes.place(x=200,y=0)

label1 = tk.Label(root, text='e for encrypt and d for decrypt', font=('Helvetica',10))
label1.place(x=10,y=50)

l_mode = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=mode, font=('calibre',10,'normal'))
l_mode.place(x=200,y=50)

label2 = tk.Label(root, text='Enter key', font=('Helvetica',10))
label2.place(x=10,y=100)

l_key = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=key, font=('calibre',10,'normal'))
l_key.place(x=200,y=100)

label3 = tk.Label(root, text='Result', font=('Helvetica',10))
label3.place(x=10,y=150)

res = tk.Entry(root,textvariable=Result, font=('calibre',10,'normal'))
res.place(x=200,y=150)

#-------------------------------------------------------
def encode(key, msg):
    enc = []
    for i in range(len(msg)):
        key_c = key[i % len(key)]
        enc_c = chr((ord(msg[i]) +
                     ord(key_c)) % 256)
        enc.append(enc_c)
    return pybase64.urlsafe_b64encode("".join(enc).encode()).decode()



def decode(key, enc):
    dec = []
    enc = pybase64.urlsafe_b64decode(enc).decode()
    for i in range(len(enc)):
        key_c = key[i % len(key)]
        dec_c = chr((256 + ord(enc[i]) - ord(key_c)) % 256)

        dec.append(dec_c)
    return "".join(dec)


def Results():
    msg = Msg.get()
    k = key.get()
    m = mode.get()
    m.lower()
    if (m == 'e'):
        Result.set(encode(k, msg))
    elif(m== 'd'):
        Result.set(decode(k, msg))
    else:
        messagebox.showinfo('TechVidvan', 'Wrong mode entered. Try again.')



def qExit():
    root.destroy()



def Reset():
    Msg.set("")
    key.set("")
    mode.set("")
    Result.set("")


btnshow = tk.Button(root, text='Show Message', foreground='green', command=Results)
btnshow.place(x=10,y=200)

btnreset = tk.Button(root, text='Reset', foreground='red', command=Reset)
btnshow.place(x=150,y=200)

btnexit = tk.Button(root, text='Exit', foreground='black', command=qExit)
btnshow.place(x=300,y=200)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You don't need to install tkinter or base64 separately at all, they're both built-in...

Comment: It is not recommend to do `from x import *` remove that and try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to install [tkinter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html) or [base64](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html) separately at all, they're both built-in. (If Tkinter support hasn't been built in to your Python installation, you will need to rebuild Python with Tkinter support, you can't just install it separately.)

- If you have indeed done `pip install tk`, then you will have installed [this package that is unrelated to `tkinter`](https://pypi.org/project/tk/0.1.0/). You'll want to uninstall it.
- Similarly, you don't need [`pybase64`](https://pypi.org/project/pybase64) to do base64 operations. Best uninstall it too.
- Thirdly, make sure your script isn't called `tk.py` itself.
- Finally, as mentioned above, the module is `tkinter`, not `tk`. It's just common to do `import tkinter as tk` for brevity.

  - Also, using `*` imports is generally not a good idea; you'll find your namespace polluted with all sorts of symbols you won't need or know where they're from.

Answer (score 1):

try to import tkinter, `from tkinter import messagebox`
you can also do the same with the rest of the imports

```
from tkinter import * as tk
import pybase64
from tkinter import messagebox
```